# Erlang NIF number return types

Tags: c, erlang, erlang-nif

I'm experimenting with NIFs and I'm confused about what number types Erlang is working with, because I'm getting some weirdness with my precisions.

Here's an example:

```
erlang:band(18446744073709551614, 5) == 4
```

And from inside a NIF which looks something like this:

```
long long l, r;

enif_get_long(env, argv[0], &l);
enif_get_long(env, argv[1], &r);

return enif_make_long(env, l & r);
```

I get a `1` as a result.

Is this something to do with the C layer not holding the correct "size" of the number? Or is it that `enif_(get|make)_long` isn't the correct way to be dealing with a number of this size? Or is it simply that NIFs can't work with numbers this large?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`18446744073709551614` is `2^64 - 2` and therefore cannot fit in a `long long`, which is most likely a 64 bit signed integer with the range `-(2^63)` to `(2^63)-1`. Also, `enif_get_long` requires a `long int`, not `long long`. You should also be getting an error value returned from `enif_get_long` because of the overflow according to the [docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_get_long) which you are not checking for.

To work on numbers upto `2^64 - 1` (which includes the number in question), you can use [`enif_get_uint64`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_get_uint64).

This code should work (untested):

```
ErlNifUInt64 l, r;
enif_get_uint64(env, argv[0], &l);
enif_get_uint64(env, argv[1], &r);
return enif_make_uint64(env, l & r);
```

You should also check the return value of `enif_get_*` to make sure you're not working on uninitialized data.

Comment: That example does work, thank you for both that and the explanation. I didn't realise that `ErlNifUInt64` existed for this case. I'll definitely add the checking, I was just playing about with trying to get this working :). Will `ErlNifUInt64` cover basically any number Erlang allows?

Comment: Nope, only `0` to `18446744073709551615` (the range of unsigned 64 bit integers).

Comment: So would an appropriate way to handle negatives as well as positives just be to check the sign on the Erlang side and implement in the NIF separately?

Comment: What range of numbers do you want to support?

Comment: Ideally, anything you can use from within Erlang (I'm thinking about porting something to NIF to make it faster, but want to keep the Erlang version's behaviour)

Comment: How do you plan on doing arithmetic/bitwise operations on numbers larger than 64 bits in C?

Comment: Fair point - looks like I should cap at the 64 bit precision and then just defer to the Erlang versions for anything higher.